# Accessing json object when property information is dynamic

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My server response is as follows:

```
{
    data : [
              {
                 name: "ADeal",
                 image: "images/adeal.png",
              },
              {
                 name: "SDeal",
                 image: "images/sdeal.png",
              }
          ]
}
```

I could able to parse it like this: *var jsonObj = JSON.parse(serverResponse)*. And also knew to access object like this: *jsonObj.data[1].name*

But in my case i get property information in variable. consider this example:

```
function dynImage(prop, el, jsonObj){
    //Here, prop contains data[1].name
    //How can i access the jsonObj and set it to el(i.e, reference of div element)

el.style.backgroundImage = url('');

}
```

Comment: so what do you want to happen? you are already accessing it

Comment: Can you post the code where you call 'dynImage' ?

Comment: @Joseph inside dynImage function, if i do **json[prop]** then its giving 'undefined'. there must be some other way

Comment: @dbaseman it doesn't matter, it just pass the property information, reference of HTMLElement, json object.

Comment: @SrikanthKshatriy what are the ***exact*** values for `prop`, `el` and `jsonObj`? try doing a `console.log()`